# Connecting to Redshift from AWS Beanstalk Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using a Node.js function in Elastic Beanstalk, I'm trying to:

1. connect to redshift via JDBC Url
2. run COPY command

In the Redshift [COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) command, I specified the `-credential` option to be an IAM User with access to the S3 bucket.

I expected that the connection would succeed since I had created a new EC2 Security Group, added a new Redshift Cluster Security Group; and added that IAM User's AWS Account ID to the EC2 Security Group.

But, the AWS Beanstalk function cannot connect to Redshift:

> { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }

I see in this AWS [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=608551&#608551) that AWS replied:

> For Beanstalk connection to Redshift. If your application is able to connect to a postgresql database, then the same approach would be used to connect to Redshift.

But, it goes onto say, as I understand, that it's an outstanding feature request:

> You may need to tweak your CIDR rules on Redshift in order to allow the network access to it. However, this has not been specifically tested by the Redshift team so I'm adding it as a feature request at this moment.

**EDIT**

After creating the Cluster Security Group, I needed to manually add it to the Redshift Cluster's Security Groups. Even after adding the new Security Group, I am getting the same `ETIMEDOUT` error in the Beanstalk logs.

Comment: Can you connect to the Redshift by using `psql` ? Are you sure you following the right syntax on credentials? Are you using Role ?

Comment: `credentials?` Yes, I was able to test locally (although my IP address is authorized per the Redshift Cluster's Security Page). `Are you using Role?` I don't think so - what's that?